# overloading << and using namespace std

Tags: c++

I need a help with understanding the following:

I overloaded << operator. I wrote a test program. I didnt include the "using namespace std" code. But the program worked out well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fraction.h"

//using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
//constructing two fractions
    Fraction a(4, 2);
    Fraction b(17, 11);
//modifying them that is entering a fractions from keyboard
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
//computing product and quotient and printing them using cout
    cout<<a*b<<endl;
    cout<<a/b<<endl;
}
```

But as you can see I used "endl" which is from standard namespace. Can you explain me the "paradox" I m getting here.

P.S I didnt include .h and .cpp file because I think they are irrelevant.

Comment: `fraction.h` probably has `using namespace std;`

Comment: I bet fraction.h includes `using namespace std;`

Comment: As others said, `fraction.h` probably has the line `using namespace std;`, which is bad practice. See [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1) as to why.

Comment: Yes it does, I checked the lihk. I am using ostream and istream to declare and overload << and >>. It doesnt work when I do std::ostream. What is an alternative if including namespace entirely is considered  a bad habit?

Comment: Use it only in cpp files where you know there won't be name clash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `#include` something, is does a straight text replacement with the file. Since you `#include "fraction.h"` and it probably has the line

```
using namespace std;
```

the main file also uses `std`.

Also note, it is not good practice to `using namespace std;` in header files since everywhere else that includes the header will also automatically use `std` which can cause conflicts if the programmer is unaware.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler works with translation unit. It takes a .cpp and then insert .h text inside the translation unit. If your header file includes `using namespace std;`, it will effectively be present in the code the compiler tries to compile.

This is a bad practice as your are shoving namespace `using` down your user throat and can induce name clashes if other namespace use the same name.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation.If I use it .cpp file, and remove using namespace std in .h file, I get the following problem. When declaring overloaded operator in .h I have to use ostream, but since std namespace is not included ostream "does not name a type",which gives me an error

Comment: @user3501: Write `std::ostream` instead.

Comment: What @MooingDuck said.

Comment: cool, I figured it out, I included <ostream>, then std::ostream worked out. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `cin` and `cout`, and the problem is using `endl`, then your `fraction.h` file is most likely including those dependencies either in one of two ways

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

or

```
using namespace std;
```